# What does positive definite matrix mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What do we mean by a matrix is positive or negative definite? Does it have any analogy with a positive real number?

Comment: How common is it to include "symmetric" (or "hermitian" in the complex case) in the definition?  And how common to omit this requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could view it as the parabola $Kx^2=y, K>0 $ taken up to higher dimensions. In place of the positive constant $K$, a positive definite matrix $A$ would ensure that the high dimensional parabola (visualise it as a bowl) takes all positive values for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. 
[image: Positive definiteness]

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239166/what-is-the-intuition-for-using-definiteness-to-compare-matrices) for why definiteness is needed when considering ordering among matrices.

Answer (score 1):

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is said to be positive definite if
$$
x^TAx>0,\quad \text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\},\tag{1}
$$
where $^T$ denotes the transpose. Similarly $A$ is negative definite if $(1)$ holds with $<0$ (also we have the terms non-negative definite and non-positive definite which is $\geq 0$ and $\leq 0$ respectively).

As for the analogy with real numbers, we note that a real number $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix. If $a=0$ then it can't satisfy $(1)$, but if $a\neq 0$ we have that $a$ is positive definite if and only if
$$
x^2a=xax>0,\quad \text{for all } x\neq 0
$$
which is equivalent to saying that $a>0$. So positive definiteness for $1\times 1$ matrices is exactly the same as the number being strictly positive.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this and more are in [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definite_matrix).

It is not analogous to positive and negative real numbers. That sense of "positive" has to do with the linear ordering of the real numbers.

"Positive definite" refers to a real matrix $A$ having the property that $x^TAx$ is positive for all nonzero vectors $x$. ($x^TAx$ is, of course, a real number in the case, but the whole of my discussion could have been done over any subring of $\Bbb R$.)

Answer (score 0):

To a (symmetric) square matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ of order $n$ with real coefficients, it is associated a bilinear form
$$
\phi(\vec x,\vec y)=(x_1,..x_n)A(y_1,...,y_n)^t
$$
and the corresponding quadratic form
$$
Q(\vec x)=\phi(\vec x,\vec x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}x_ix_j.
$$
The quadratic form $Q$ (and so the matrix $A$ by extension) is said *positive definite* if
$$
Q(\vec x)>0\qquad\text{for all $\vec x\neq0$}.
$$
When $n=1$ the matrix is just a scalar $a$, and positive definiteness indeed means that $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

To add to all the other answers, Posiitive definite matrices are the only matrices with a unique square root which is also positive definite, something reminiscent of non-negative numbers.