# Comparing two covariance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the textbook I am reading they use positive definiteness (semi-positive definiteness) to compare two covariance matrices. The idea being that is A-B is pd then B is smaller than A. But I'm struggling to get the intuition of this relationship?

There is a similar thread here:

[What is the intuition for using definiteness to compare matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239166/what-is-the-intuition-for-using-definiteness-to-compare-matrices)

Although the answers are nice they don't really address the intutition.

Here is an example I find confusing:

$\begin{pmatrix} 16 && 12\\ 12 && 9 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 2\\ 2 && 4 \end{pmatrix}$

now here the determinant of the difference is -25 so the relation is not pd or even psd and so the first matrix is not greater than the first?

I simply want to compare two 3*3 covariance matrices to see which is smallest? It would seem more intuitive to me to use the something like the euclidean norm to compare them?
However this would mean that the first matrix above is greater than the second matix. Moreover I only ever see the pd/psd citerion used to compare covariance matrices.

Can someone explain why pd/psd is better than using another measure such as the euclidean norm?

Comment: What you're calling the "ps/psd" comparison criterion is equivalent to $A>B$ iff $x^T(A-B) x>0$ for all $x\ne 0$, i.e., $A-B$ is positive definite. That's useful and powerful. It crops up all over the place in statistics & probability theory. If you used Euclidean norm or some such thing, you'd find very little use for it in these fields. And the Euclidean norm doesn't ORDER two matrices. (It tells you "how far apart" they are.) Also, very important: the "ps/psd" comparison is NOT a "total" ordering. There are matrices $A$ and $B$ such that NONE of $A>B$, $B>A$, and $A=B$ holds. That's life.